# How to write a function that is based on oops and i can return the database values so i can stop rewriting of code?

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

Right now I am writing a program in core PHP, but I am not able to write a perfect oops concept as I m rewriting the code many times.

for Eg.

```
public function all()
    {
        $init = new Database;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
        // Result
        $result = $init->conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
?>
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Action</th>
                        <th scope="col">id</th>
                        <th scope="col">Category name</th>
                        <th scope="col">Category description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <form action="update_categories.php?update_id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" method="post">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update">Update</button>
                                </form>
                                <form action="delete_categories.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" method="post">
                                    <button type="submit" name="delete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                                </form>
                            </td>
                            <td><?php echo $row["id"] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row["category_name"] ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row["category_description"] ?></td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    } ?>
                </tbody>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">id</th>
                            <th scope="col">Category name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Category description</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">no result</th>
                            <td>no result</td>
                            <td>no result</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <?php
                }
            }
```

So here you can see I have to fetch the data from the database but in this function, I have included Html too so if you want to add database data to another place I have to write the function for that again and fetch the values.

Is there any way I can only fetch the value and i can use the function to print it wherever I want.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I would suggest starting with some PHP tutorials, there are plenty of them online.

Comment: any tutorial in particular?